# Changing NodeJS variables at runtime

Tags: node.js

I've got a simple FeathersJS server. I want to change certain things in its config without restarting it, such as disallow creating new users.

So, basically, I want to change a couple of variables at runtime.

It definitely sounds like something that's got complete solutions written somewhere.

My thoughts are to expose a callback that, according to its args, changes the variables of interest, then call the callback with something like `inquirer` or expose WebSockets that execute the callback accordingly.

**Please tell me how to best solve this problem, and - if possible - point me to some existing solutions as well.**

Answer (score 1):

To change something inside your nodejs process from outside the process, you need to expose some external connectivity that can make the change for you.  There are an infinite set of choices, but a webSocket/socket.io server or an http server are probably the most common.

If this is typically just a transaction, not a whole sequence of changes, then a simple http server on a port that is not accessible from the outside world is probably the most appropriate way to do this.  You then just create routes on the http server that accept the desired changes and the code in the routes themselves changes the internal variables accordingly.  If you chose some other interface such as a webSocket or socket.io server, the concept would be the same.